# how can I slide the view down with a gesture when it appears on my uiviewController in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have an ios app and there I have a uiviewcontroller. I also have a button there with a function that brings another view to screen. This is my setup:

[image]

in story board it looks like this:

[image]

By default the view is hidden:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.hidden = true
}
```

and the button makes it visible:

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    view.hidden = false   
}
```

But how can I make it disappear when user swipe it down?
I want to achieve the effect that when user starts slowly swiping it down the view will follow his touch - is that achievable?

Comment: Yes, it is. What have you thought of doing? What did Google teach you? What went wrong when you tried to implement it?

Comment: I tried to put in on uiscrollview, but that covered the rest of the uiviewcontroller and all other buttons were not clickable... I also tried to attach a uigesturerecognizer, but then a single swipe (no matter how "long" it was) was making the view disappear, so the view was not following the user's touch...

Comment: So you want a pan instead of a swipe gesture